# Asking for reference for short contract job?

Tags: references

I got a two week contract for a reputable company. Unfortunately they didn't need us for as long as the thought so the reduced all the contractors to one week. One week is so short I probably wouldn't even include it on most resumes. Is there a point asking for a reference? Since I never even had the opportunity to work closely with full time staff, I don't know what they could say about me.

If I don't get a reference should I ask for at least a contact number or email address? Is there a difference between the two?

Technically speaking the recruiting agency who found me the position decided it would simplify the paper work if they hired me (i.e. paid me) as opposed to the actual company am working for.

Comment: Is it common in your profession to work such short contracts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of just a single week of work, unless you made a connection directly with **a person who is willing to be a reference for you** I would not even bother to put this on my resume.

Even if this person were willing to be a reference, you may still wish to consider leaving the experience off your resume, but instead **use this person as a professional reference**.

YMMV

Answer (score -1):

Seriously? No. I do not even list anything below 3 months on my list of prjects done. I don't even accept contracts below 3 months.

If you are in a profession where you work short term - you will get thousands of references. Not worth anything.

If you are in IT or something - no, as I said. Not even worth the paper. If anything it shows you lack real references of meaning.